# openconnect fails with "No SSO handler"

Tags: vpn, openvpn, cisco, openconnect

Previously I could connect to my office Windows machine remotely from Ubuntu using:

```
sudo openvpn --mktun --dev tun1
sudo ifconfig tun1 up
sudo openconnect ${VPN_SERVER_ADDRESS} --authgroup=${VPN_AUTH_GROUP} --interface=tun1
```

...I would then use Remmina to establish the connection to my machine. When I was finished with Remmina, I would then shutdown with:

```
sudo ifconfig tun1 down
sudo openvpn --rmtun --dev tun1
```

A few days ago, this stopped working. After the call to `openconnect`, the last 3 messages I get are:

```
Please complete the authentication process in the AnyConnect Login window.
No SSO handler
Failed to complete authentication
```

The "AnyConnect Login window" mentioned (or any other window) does not appear. How can I provide a suitable SSO handler, or otherwise get past the problem? I have tried adding `--external-browser=firefox` (or `--external-browser=/usr/bin/firefox`, and also with chromium), but this makes no difference.  I would like to use an open source solution, and I'm using Ubuntu 23.04.

Comment: Running into this as well.  Did you ever find a solution?